# Grouping $d$-digits codes based on their distinct digits

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

I’m trying to count all the possible $d$-digits codes could be built with $M$ digits in a way that I could group them based on their distinct digits. However, there is a caveat. One out of the $M$ digits is less important, hence, I don’t consider them as a distinct digit.

Let me clarify with an example. Consider $d = 3$ and $M = 4$ and the set of digits are 1 – 4. Digit 1 here is less important and is ignored in the process of grouping. Some grouping examples are shown below

{"111": 0,
"411": 1,
"333": 1,
"123": 2,
"223": 2,
"234": 3}.

For this example, there are 6 members in group 3, 36 in group 2 and 21 in group 1.

Interestingly enough, I found a relation for $d < M$ that can give me each group’s population. Ignoring group 0 from the count, there remains $M^d-1$ possible codes. We then have

$M^{d} - 1 = \sum_{i = 1}^{d} \alpha_i \prod_{z = 1}^{i}(M - z),$

where $\alpha_i \prod_{z = 1}^{i}(M - z)$ is the population of group $i$. For the example above, $\alpha_1=7$, $\alpha_2=6$ and $\alpha_3=1$. They can be easily derived recursively knowing that $\alpha_d=1$.

Is this relation well-known or something? If it is, can you point out a reference or name that I can further search it by.
Also, what do $\alpha_i$’s represent exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us count the number of members in the group $i$. Let $e$ denote the 'less important' element, I will call it a null. We have:

- $M$ - size of the alphabet (with one null),
- $d$ - length of the word,
- $i$ - the number of distinct non-null elements in the word.

We ask for the number of sequences of length $d$, containing exactly $i$ elements from $M$. Certainly, the word can contain only $i$ such elements with nulls on the remaining positions or it can contain no nulls at all.

Firstly, assume that there are no nulls. What is the number of sequences of length $d$ using some $i$ elements, such that each element is used at least once? This is exactly the number of surjections from the set $\{1, 2, \dots, d\}$ onto the set $\{1, 2, \dots, i\}$, so the number of such sequences is by the inclusion-exclusion principle equal to:
$$P_1 (d, i) = \sum_{j=0}^i (-1)^j \binom{i}{j} (i-j)^d = i! S(d, i),$$

where $S$ stands for the Stirling number of the second kind. Now, as we calculated $P_1$ for a fixed set of $i$ elements, we need to take into account that we may select these elements in $\binom{M-1}{i}$ ways (we leave the null element). So we have
$$P_2(M, d, i) = \binom{M-1}{i} P_1(d, i) = \binom{M-1}{i} i! S(d, i).$$

$P_2$ is the number of sequences in the group $i$ if no nulls are allowed. However, including nulls is not difficult. We know that there are at least $0$ nulls and at most $d-i$ nulls, because our sequence must have at least one of each unique element. Also, we can select places for $k$ nulls in $\binom{d}{k}$ ways. So, the number of elements in the group $i$ is equal exactly to:
$$P_3 (M, d, i) = \sum_{k=0}^{d-i} \binom{d}{k}P_2(M, d-k, i) = \sum_{k=0}^{d-i}\binom{d}{k}\binom{M-1}{i}i!S(d-k, i) = $$
$$= \frac{(M-1)!}{(M-i-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{d-i}\binom{d}{k}S(d-k, i)$$

Using the property of Stirling numbers:
$$S(n+1, m+1) = \sum_{j=m}^n \binom{n}{j}S(j, m)$$
we obtain
$$P_3(M, d, i) = \frac{(M-1)!}{(M-i-1)!}S(d+1, i+1).$$

Note, that what you have expressed using a product may be rewritten with factorials:
$$\Pi_{z=1}^i (M-z) = (M-1)(M-2)\dots (M-i) = \frac{1\cdot 2 \cdot \dots \cdot (M-1)}{1\cdot 2 \cdot \dots \cdot (M-i-1)}=\frac{(M-1)!}{(M-i-1)!}.$$

So, to sum up, your value $\alpha_i$ is equal to $S(4, i+1)$, because you set $d=3$ in the example. The Stirling numbers of the second kind in fact follow a simple recurrence relation, i.e.:
$$S(n+1, m) = m \cdot S(n, m) + S(n, m-1)$$
which may be useful in your calculations.